# How to prevent overlapping content during window resizing

Tags: html, css

I have a little problem --
I have two div on left and right, as my screen resolution is 1280*768, they work fine here. but when I reduce the window size it overlaps each other ... like left one is reduce in width and right one make that happen ...

here is my code..

```
<div class="shareBar" align="right">
        ......
 </div> 
<div class="content">     
    .....   
 </div>
```

and my css code is here

```
.content{
    position:relative;
    margin: 110px 5px 10px 5px;
    min-width:700px;

    }


.shareBar{
    position:relative;
}
```

here shareBar overlaps content...

And I want to make this shareBar always in a static position and when window re-size occurs a horizontal scroll-bar should appears so that content will always in in a static size. Or otherwise shareBar should reside under content.
Is it possible with pure css?

Comment: Don't use position relative. Position relative literally means move it from where it should normally be display by the amount I specify. It normally displays without overlapping. You are moving it to overlap. Get rid of all that CSS and try simply float: right; on the share bar.

Comment: @NewBiL use width:100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make `.sharebar` appear in the same place and provoke a horizontal scrollbar on window resize, you should remove `align="right"` from the HTML give it `position:absolute` as well as a specified location in the CSS.  For example:

```
.shareBar{
    position:absolute;
    left:900px;
}
```